# How to associate public subnets with default route table instead of newly created route table

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, terraform-modules

I'm using the [Terraform vpc module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest) from the Registry. The module automatically creates a `public_internet_gateway` route table and associates my public subnets with it. However, it doesn't set it as the vpc's main route table.

1. Is there a way to make it the main route table via the module?
2. If not, is there a way to make the module associate the subnets with the default route table and create the right route to the igw?

I'm new to Terraform and couldn't find a clear answer in the docs. Here's what I have so far:

```
# Retrieve the list of AZs in the current AWS region
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

locals {
  app_name = var.app_name
  region   = "us-east-1"
  vpc_cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
  azs      = slice(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, 0, 2)
}

module "vpc" {
  source                  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  name                    = "${local.app_name}-vpc"
  cidr                    = local.vpc_cidr
  enable_dns_hostnames    = true
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  azs            = local.azs
  public_subnets = [for key, value in local.azs : cidrsubnet(local.vpc_cidr, 8, key + 100)]

  manage_default_route_table = true
  # default_route_table_routes = {
  #   cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  #   gateway_id = module.vpc.igw_id
  # }
  manage_default_security_group = false
  manage_default_network_acl    = false

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to have routes in the main route table?

Comment: What's wrong with the code? You seem to use `default_route_table_routes` but haven't explained what's the issue with that.

Comment: maybe you could just add a aws_route_table_association to the main and the igw.

Comment: @Marcin I commented that out because I don't think that was the right way to configure that argument. It didn't work, and the documentation for that piece is a little confusing. The problem is that the module creates a public route table, but it doesn't set it as the main rt for the vpc. I was just asking if that was possible to do that within the module. RIght now, I'm using the `aws_main_route_table_association` resource to do it

Comment: @SikiShen Yeah, I'm setting the new route table as the main rt with the `aws_main_route_table_association` resource after, but I was just wondering If I could do it within the module.

Comment: @MarkoE don't I need to do that to reach instances? Ex: I have Apache web servers in my public subnets. those subnets are associated with `public_rt` and routed to the igw. However, the main route table is set to the default route table. I won't be able to access the servers through their public IP, right? Maybe I'm mistaken. I just started learning AWS DevOps (very little IT background)

Comment: @MarkoE I guess, you're right. I was mistaken. I could've sworn that was the case earlier. You live and you learn... Thanks for getting me to question my own reasoning haha.

Comment: You cannot do it with module you are using anyway. See line 139 https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/blob/master/main.tf